# SQL query or cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with two different stamps. Let's call them oristamp and tarstamp. I need to find only the records that for the same oristamp have different tarstamps. It is possible to do that with a simple query? I think should be used a cursor but I'm not familiar with that. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a sub-query to find oristamp values having at least two different tarstamp values. Join with that sub-query:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
  join (select oristamp from tablename
        group by oristamp
        having count(distinct tarstamp) >= 2) t2 on t1.oristamp = t2.oristamp
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @jarlh. Seeing becomes easier than it looked. Always learning...

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understand the question. I am assuming you want all rows where more than 1 distinct value for tarstamp exists for each oristamp.

```
DECLARE @t table(tarstamp int, oristamp int)
INSERT @t values
(1,1),
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,2)

;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT *, 
    max(tarstamp) over (partition by oristamp) mx, 
    min(tarstamp) over (partition by oristamp) mn
FROM @t
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE 
WHERE mx <> mn
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of different `oristamp`s per `tarstamp` and select the rows that have `tarstamp`s with more than one `oristamp`, E.g.:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mytable
WHERE  tarstamp IN (SELECT   tarstamp
                    FROM     mytable
                    GROUP BY tarstamp
                    HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT oristamp) > 1)
```

Comment: Don't you need a correlated sub-query?

Comment: @jarlh you could do it like that, but you don't really have to

Comment: Thank you @Mureinik, but I need to change the `WHERE` clause to obtain desired results and exactly same results of @jarlh query:    `SELECT *    FROM mytable    WHERE oristamp IN (SELECT oristamp    FROM mytable    GROUP BY oristamp     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tarstamp) > 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, which will return all those combination which contain different oristamp.

`select distinct  z.* 
 from
 ( select oristamp, count(*) ct 
   from mytable
   Group by oristamp
 )z,
 ( Select oristamp, tarstamp, count(*) ct 
   from mytable
   Group by oristamp, tarstamp
 )y
 Where z.oristamp =y.oristamp
 And z.ct != y.ct`

Comment: A code-only answer is considered to be of low quality. Could you please add some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, using MIN and MAX aggregate functions will perform better as  COUNT(DISTINCT oristamp) > 1 adds complexity to the execution plan:

```
SELECT   tarstamp
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY tarstamp
HAVING   MIN(oristamp) != MAX(oristamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a simple join:

```
DECLARE @t table(tarstamp int, oristamp int)
INSERT @t values
(1,1),
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,2)


SELECT t1.*
FROM @t t1
INNER JOIN @t t2
    ON t1.oristamp = t2.oristamp
WHERE t1.tarstamp <> t2.tarstamp
```

Comment: Please explain the query on how it would fix the issue.

Comment: @Phani this query returns the same results as the accepted answer! it returns all records that for the same oristamp have different tarstamps. That's how!

Comment: Sure @Steve. But it would make more sense if you could describe on how  this is different/better than others.